# Problema para criar a base de dados usando EntityFramework com configuração por DbConfiguration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estou estudando o EntityFramework, escrevendo dois contextos para entender como lidar com ele quando meu domínio conter **muitas classes de entidade**. Que então seriam representadas por muitos DbSet´s no contexto, tornando "pesada" sua inicialização.
Imagino que essa seja a forma correta de se trabalhar quando se possui um modelo com muitas classes!

Então comecei meus testes escrevendo o seguinte domínio, unicamente para teste:

```cs
public class Empresa
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(70)]
    public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
}

public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]        
    public string Senha { get; set; }
}
```

O contexto criei da seguinte forma:

```cs
public class EfConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public EfConfiguration() {       
        SetProviderServices(SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, 
            SqlProviderServices.Instance);
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new SqlConnectionFactory());
    }
}

[DbConfigurationType(typeof(EfConfiguration))]
public abstract class CustomContext : DbContext
{
    protected CustomContext(): base("DefaultConnection") {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
}

public class EmpresaContext : CustomContext
{
    public DbSet<Empresa> Empresas { get; set; }
}

public class UsuarioContext : CustomContext
{
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
}
```

Assim está o **App.config** de minha aplicação console para teste:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection"
      connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=TestEF;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Enfim, para não colocar mais um monte de código meu app console para teste:

```cs
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Instanciando as classes ...");

            var empresaRepository = new EmpresaRepository<Empresa>();
            var usuarioRepository = new UsuarioRepository<Usuario>();

            Console.WriteLine("Obtendo ...");

            empresaRepository.Obter();
            usuarioRepository.Obter();

            Console.WriteLine("Pronto!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.GetBaseException().Message);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Os métodos `Obter()` irão efetuar os seguintes comandos de minha classe Repository genérica:

```cs
public IQueryable<T> Obter(Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition = null)
{
    var result = (IQueryable<T>)_context.Set<T>();
    if (condition != null)
        result = result.Where(condition);
    return result;
}
```

O meu problema é que a string "Pronto!" do último comando `Console.WriteLine()` é impressa no console do Windows mas o banco de dados não está sendo criado. Enfim, não está sendo impresso nenhuma mensagem de erro!

**O que pode estar causando isso?**

**Obs**: Sem usar o `DbConfiguration` e escrevendo App´s com EF da forma tradicional não tenho problemas.

---

#### EDIT

Seguindo orientações do usuário Cigano Morrisson tentei especificar a criação do banco utilizando inicializadores para o contexto:

Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways());
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways());

Infelizmente também não funcionou!

Então tentei também com Migrations. Para mais de um contexto precisei especificar:

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName EmpresaContext -MigrationsDirectory Migrations\EmpresaContext
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName UsuarioContext -MigrationsDirectory Migrations\UsuarioContext
```

Adicionando versão:

```
Add-Migration -ConfigurationTypeName AppConsoleTest.Migrations.EmpresaContext.Configuration "Initial"
Add-Migration -ConfigurationTypeName AppConsoleTest.Migrations.UsuarioContext.Configuration "Initial"
```

Criando e atualizando banco de dados:

```
Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName AppConsoleTest.Migrations.EmpresaContext.Configuration
Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName AppConsoleTest.Migrations.UsuarioContext.Configuration
```

Assim o banco de dados foi criado. Ambos atingiram a mesma base de dados e as duas tabelas apareceram.

Logo, experimentei comentando `//[DbConfigurationType(typeof(EfConfiguration))]` da `CustomContext`, removi os arquivos do Migrations e removi também os inicializadores `Database.SetInitializer` e ao executar a aplicação, nos métodos `Obter()` dos objetos de repositório (`empresaRepository` e `usuarioRepository`) a base é criada e as tabelas também, no mesmo banco.
Com isso deduzi que o erro está em minha classe de configuração, a `EfConfiguration`.

**O que esta errado?**

Answer (score 1):

Você não especificou de nenhuma forma como este(s) contexto(s) deve(m) ser criado(s).

Há algumas maneiras:

### 1. Habilitando `Migrations`

No Visual Studio, vá em <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Other Windows</kbd> > <kbd>Package Manager Console</kbd>. No prompt que aparecer, digite o seguinte:

> Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations

Pode ser que ele peça para especificar qual contexto você quer as `migrations`. Feito isso, digite:

> Add-Migration Inicial

Será criada uma `migration` inicial, contendo todas as entidades que devem ser criadas no seu banco de dados. Para efetivamente criar essas entidades, digite:

> Update-Database

O código deve funcionar sem problemas, se tudo foi feito certo.

### 2. Usar uma configuração que não necessita de `migrations`

Neste caso, você terá que configurar seu(s) contexto(s) para terem inicializadores de bases de dados. Ou seja, coloque o seguinte código no seu `Main` ou no construtor do seu contexto:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EmpresaContext>());
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<UsuarioContext>());
```

Comment: Com o `Database.SetInitializer(..)` não deu certo. Estou procurando o nome do comando para especificar uma pasta para o Migrations, para cada contexto, para ele permitir mais de um e então eu poder testar. Caso contrário ele pede para qual contexto desejo criar e então não permite criar para o outro depois.

Comment: Bom. Com o Migrations e usando um só contexto a base é criada sem problemas com o comando `update-database`. Mas.. uma perguntinha, não deveria criar sozinho? O EF já não cria sozinho, sem configurações extras?

Comment: Certo, com migrations para os dois contextos também cria a base de dados.

Comment: Respondendo sua pergunta sobre criar sozinho: não, não deveria criar sozinho, porque a aplicação não sabe por onde começar. Ela pode usar SQL Server Express, LocalDb ou uma base de algum outro provedor. Portanto, é o programador que precisa indicar o caminho.

Comment: Pois removi o decorador `//[DbConfigurationType(typeof(EfConfiguration))]` da `CustomContext`, removi o Migrations e o `Database.SetInitializer` e funcionou! E ainda assim o projeto cria sozinho assim que o comando `Obter()` é chamado. Também, descobri com isso que o problema é em meu `DbConfiguration`. Grato!